# jQuery: fadeOut only when parent div is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

jQuery

```
$(".window-container").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("fast");
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="window-container">
    <div class="window-wrap">
        <div class="window-content">
             asdf
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a link that makes `window-container` and each child div appear. (Like a Facebook popup)

To close `window-container` I want to be able to click anywhere except within the `window-content` div. Because if I have an input contained within, and I focus on it, it will close everything.

So how can I have it only close if a user clicks the `window-container` or `window-wrap` divs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check [`event.target`](http://%24target.is%28%27div.window-container%27%29) to make sure the `click` event originated from `div.window-container` or `div.window-wrap`.

```
$(".window-container").click(function(e)
{
    if ($(e.target).is('div.window-container, div.window-wrap'))
    {
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
```

Alternately:

```
$(".window-container").click(function(e)
{
    if ($(e.target).has('div.window-content').length)
    {
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to stop the propagation of the event (*with [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)*), when it is initiated from inside the `.window-content` element.

```
$('.window-content').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This way the click event will never reach the `.window-container` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".window-container").click(function (e) {
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(".window-wrap, .window-content").click(function (e) {
        $(".window-container").css("display", "block !important");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $("body").click(function () {
        $(".window-container").fadeOut("fast");
    });
```